# Simplest 2D array, using g++, with one variable dimension?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I would like to make an array like this:

```
double array[variable][constant];
```

Only the first dimension is variable. Declaring this with a variable as the first dimension gives initialization errors. Is there a simple way to do this with pointers or other basic types?

Comment: You probably want `std::vector<std::array<double,constant>>(variable)`.

Comment: I would write a class to wrap a single `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza why? For speed reasons?

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, the single vector to ensure the data are all contiguous, and the wrapper to make sure the invariants can be maintained.

Comment: @juanchopanza Note the vector contains array, so data is contiguous. Could you explain what "invariants can be maintained" means, please?

Comment: @NeilKirk The data in a vector of `std::array` would be in the same data block, but all the elements need not be contiguous. The standard allows for this, unfortunately. For invariants, I mean the case where `variable` and/or `constant` may be fixed, set at runtime, but at construction.

Comment: @juanchopanza I still don't understand. Both vector and array have contiguous elements. It's in the standard.

Comment: @NeilKirk Imagine if an array had a tiny little something after its data elements. Well, the standard does not rule that out, which means that in a vector or array of arrays, the elements themselves are not guaranteed to be contiguous, even if they are all in the same block. It is a pity, because it is even hard to imagine an implementation that would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable length arrays didn't make it in the latest C++ standard. You can use `std::vector` instead

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > arr;
```

Or, to fix for example the second dimension (to 10 in this example), you can do

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 10> > arr1; // to declare a fixed second dimension
```

Otherwise you need to use old pointers,

```
double (*arr)[10]; // pointer to array-of-10-doubles
```

In light of @Chiel's comment, to increase performance you can do

```
typedef double (POD_arr)[10];
std::vector<POD_arr> arr;
```

In this way, you have all data stored contiguously in the memory, so access should be as fast as using a plain old `C` array.

PS: it seems that the last declaration is against the standard, since as @juanchopanza mentioned, POD arrays do not satisfy the requirements for data to be stored in an STL array (they are not assignable). However, `g++` compiles the above 2 declarations without any problems, and can use them in the program. But `clang++` fails though.

Comment: I would strongly advise against the nested types in performance critical cases, since the total array won't be contiguous in memory

Comment: @Chiel, both `std::vector` and `std::array` are contiguous, but yes, the total object may not have the data contiguous because a `std::array` occupies more than the wrapped array inside. Then I guess one can define a `std::vector<POD_arr>`, where `POD_arr` is just a `typedef double (POD_arr)[10]`. This should make everything contiguous, if I'm not wrong somehow.

Comment: You can't store plain arrays in a standard library container. The vector of arrays is quite a good solution. The data are in a single block. There *may* be padding between the arrays, but the effect of that would be minimal. The only issue is if there is a requirement for all the elements to be contiguous.

Comment: @juanchopanza, are you sure about not being able to store POD arrays? I just test it and it seems to work, initialized fine, write/read OK, no segfauls.

Comment: @vsoftco Pretty sure, plain arrays are not assignable or copyable.

Comment: @vsoftco I meant indeed the total object, which is quite often essential for high performance with multi-dimensional objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza Another `g++` bug, I keep finding them every day :) So the code compiles with `g++`, can assign elements to the `vector<POD_arr>`, can the display them etc. However, as you mentioned, cannot copy/move/assign it. However, `clang++` does NOT compile it.

Comment: `std::array` is a template - I don't think it should need any data beyond a `T[N]`, so that `std::vector<std::array<double,10> >` ought to store all of the data in a contiguous 80 byte block.

Comment: @sfjac doesn't it have to store some pointers to member functions?

Comment: If you mean a vtable pointer, `std::array` is unlikely to have any virtual functions. (Whether this is a language requirement I don't know but as a user of this sort of template array class I would definitely be disappointed if it did.)

Comment: @sfjac, no, of course, STL containers don't have virtual members, as far as I know. I meant member functions, but now I found out that they are not actually stored in the instantiation. So you are right, the only issue may be padding, as juanchopanza mentioned, however it shouldn't make a big difference. Although it seems there is no padding according to `sizeof`, however it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Because of its template nature, you can static_assert on the size - I think this should suffice to check at compile time whether you will have problems; e.g. `static_assert(6*sizeof(int) == sizeof(std::array<int, 6>), "sizeof array inconsistency");`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that, but it is not a true 2D array. It is based on the general idea that internally a multiple dimension array is necessarily linear with the rule that for an array of dimensions (n, m) you have : `array2d[i, j] = array1d[j + i*m]`

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class dynArray {
private:
    double *array;
    int dim2;
public:
    dynArray(int variable, int constant) {
        array = new double[variable * constant];
    dim2 = constant;
    }
    ~dynArray() {
        delete array;
    }

    double value(int i, int j) {
        return array[j + i * dim2];
    }

    double *pt(int i, int j) {
        return array + j + i * dim2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    dynArray d(3,4);
    *d.pt(2,3) = 6.;
    cout << "Result : " << d.value(2,3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```